# Get specific substring cell value in a column of a dataframe pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to access some cells in columns in a dataframe using pandas.
Unfortunately, I got an error saying :

> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in
> _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)    1620             key = item_from_zerodim(key)    1621             if not is_integer(key):
> -> 1622                 raise TypeError("Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key")    1623     1624             # validate
> the location
>
> TypeError: Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key

The python code:

```
#Calculate the cost, revenue, and profit for each day in each year.
def calculateParametersOnedayEachMonth(ptype,month, year):

  price = 0
  r = 0
  
  data = pd.DataFrame(readData)
  #print(data[["Date"]])

  for x in range(data.size):
    #print(x)
    if data.iloc[[x]["Date"]] == "1/"+month+"/"+str(year)+"12:00:00" :
       print("I am inside")
       index1 = x
       index2 = x+24
       for index1 in range(index2):
         if type == "PV":
           price = price + data.iloc[[index1]['PVPrice']]
           print(price)
           loadForcast = data.iloc[[index1]['PVLoadForecast']]
           powerForcast = data.iloc[[index1]['PVPowerForecast']]
           r = r+(loadForcast-powerForcast)  
           print(r)
         elif type == "DG":
           price = price + data.iloc[[index1]['DGPrices']]
           loadForcast = data.iloc[[index1]['DGLoad forecast']]
           powerForcast = data.iloc[[index1]['DGPowerForecast']]
           r = r+(loadForcast-powerForcast)
         elif type == "Wind":
           price = price + data.iloc[[index1]['WPrice']]
           loadForcast = data.iloc[[index1]['WindLoadforecast']]
           powerForcast = data.iloc[[index1]['WindPowerForecast']]
           r = r+(loadForcast-powerForcast)
         elif type == "BES":
           price = price + data.iloc[[index1]['BESPrice']]
           loadForcast = data.iloc[[index1]['BESLoadForecast']]
           powerForcast = data.iloc[[index1]['BESPowerForecast']]
           r = r+(loadForcast-powerForcast)
         elif type == "Zonal":
           price = price + data.iloc[[index1]['ZonalPrice']]
           loadForcast = data.iloc[[index1]['ZonalLoadForecast']]
           powerForcast = data.iloc[[index1][' ZonalPowerForecast']]
           r = r+(loadForcast-powerForcast)
         else: print("Sorry, this type is not provided by dataset")
       break
   

  avgPrice = price / 24
  avgRevenue = r/24

  print("Day-Ahead Energy Price",avgPrice)
  print("Day-Ahead Revenue",avgPrice)
 


  allValues = {  "Cost": avgPrice , "Reveneu": avgRevenue}

  if type=="PV":
    if year == "2011":
      listAllDaysParameters2011_PV.append(allValues)
    elif year == "2012":
      listAllDaysParameters2012_PV.append(allValues)
    elif year == "2013":
      listAllDaysParameters2013_PV.append(allValues)
    elif year == "2014":
      listAllDaysParameters2014_PV.append(allValues)
    elif year == "2015":
      listAllDaysParameters2015_PV.append(allValues)
    elif year == "2016":
      listAllDaysParameters2016_PV.append(allValues)
    else: print("This year is not provided by the dataset")

  elif type=="DG":
    if year == 2011:
      listAllDaysParameters2011_DG.append(allValues)
    elif year == 2012:
      listAllDaysParameters2012_DG.append(allValues)
    elif year == 2013:
      listAllDaysParameters2013_DG.append(allValues)
    elif year == 2014:
      listAllDaysParameters2014_DG.append(allValues)
    elif year == 2015:
      listAllDaysParameters2015_DG.append(allValues)
    elif year == 2016:
      listAllDaysParameters2016_DG.append(allValues)
    else: print("This year is not provided by the dataset")

  elif type=="Wind":
    if year == 2011:
      listAllDaysParameters2011_Wind.append(allValues)
    elif year == 2012:
      listAllDaysParameters2012_Wind.append(allValues)
    elif year == 2013:
      listAllDaysParameters2013_Wind.append(allValues)
    elif year == 2014:
      listAllDaysParameters2014_Wind.append(allValues)
    elif year == 2015:
      listAllDaysParameters2015_Wind.append(allValues)
    elif year == 2016:
      listAllDaysParameters2016_Wind.append(allValues)
    else: print("This year is not provided by the dataset")

  elif type=="BES":
    if year == 2011:
      listAllDaysParameters2011_BES.append(allValues)
    elif year == 2012:
      listAllDaysParameters2012_BES.append(allValues)
    elif year == 2013:
      listAllDaysParameters2013_BES.append(allValues)
    elif year == 2014:
      listAllDaysParameters2014_BES.append(allValues)
    elif year == 2015:
      listAllDaysParameters2015_BES.append(allValues)
    elif year == 2016:
      listAllDaysParameters2016_BES.append(allValues)
    else: print("This year is not provided by the dataset")

  elif type=="Zonal":
    if year == 2011:
      listAllDaysParameters2011_Zonal.append(allValues)
    elif year == 2012:
      listAllDaysParameters2012_Zonal.append(allValues)
    elif year == 2013:
      listAllDaysParameters2013_Zonal.append(allValues)
    elif year == 2014:
      listAllDaysParameters2014_Zonal.append(allValues)
    elif year == 2015:
      listAllDaysParameters2015_Zonal.append(allValues)
    elif year == 2016:
      listAllDaysParameters2016_Zonal.append(allValues)
    else: print("Sorry, this year is not provided by the dataset")

  else: print("Sorry, this type is not provided by the dataset")
```

The error about this line of code:

```
data.iloc[[x]["Date"]] == "1/9/"+str(year)+"12:00:00"
```

How can fix this error as I tried multiple solutions on stack overflow, but nothing is working with me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It is difficult to read your entire code, follow your logic, and fix what is wrong. becuz it is not reproducible. If you create simple and reproducible example and attach the desired result, it will be much easier to solve.

Comment: Have you tried `.loc` instead of `.iloc`? `.iloc` only takes integers because it doesn't use your actual index, it just counts up the position from 0. Maybe `data.loc[x["Date"]]`

Comment: i've got 'int' object is not subscriptable.

Comment: Also you should be using vectorized operations instead of a for loop

Comment: how it will be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's how I modify that part of your code:**

```
if data.loc[x, "Date"] == "1/" + month + "/" + str(year) + " 12:00:00":
    print("I am inside")
    # Rest of your code...
```